# A question related to the inverse image of a set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This may seem like (... or, may be it is) a very trivial question.

Consider a function $f\colon X\to Y$ (Assume that both $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty). Consider the inverse image of $Y$ under $f$, defined by $\:f^{-1}(Y):=\{x\in X:f(x)\in Y\}$. Then is it necessarily true that $f^{-1}(Y)=X$?

**My thoughts:** Cleary, $f^{-1}(Y)\subset X$ (follows from the definition). Now given $x\in X$, $f(x)\in Y$, so $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$. Hence $X\subset f^{-1}(Y)$, so $X=f^{-1}(Y)$.

Is this reasoning correct? I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: No need to explicitly assume that $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty. It's still true if $X$ is empty, and if $X$ is nonempty then $Y$ must be also since $f$ is a function. Don't fear zero! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. $\phantom{long stuff to bypass the lower limit}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true from the definition of the set.

Answer (score -1):

It is true to the degree that $f^{-1}$ is defined for all members of $Y$. But this is not always the case. For example, you can define
$$
  \sin : X=\mathbb R \to Y=[-1:1],
$$
and then indeed $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ as you explain. But you could also have defined
$$
  \sin : X=\mathbb R \to Y=\mathbb R,
$$
and in that case $f^{-1}$ is not defined on all of $Y$. So there are cases one needs to be wary of when defining the image $Y$ larger than strictly necessary (strictly necessary would mean setting $Y=f(X)$).

This issue also crops up when you do something like
$$
  \sin : X=[0,\pi] \to Y=\mathbb R.
$$
This is, strictly speaking, a valid definition: The sine, when applied to the range $[0,\pi]$, produces values that are real numbers. But when you consider  $f^{-1}(Y)$ you end with either $[-\pi/2,+\pi/2)$ or some other periodically shifted interval of the real axis, or if you allow for $f^{-1}$ to be multi-valued, you'll get $f^{-1}(Y)=\mathbb R$.

So, you need to be quite specific about how you define $Y$. If you choose the minimal definition $Y=f(X)$, then you can make the inverse statement $X=f^{-1}(Y)$ if you define $f^{-1}$ appropriately (which, as the example of the sine shows, isn't always totally trivial).

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever.